# google tag manager working on included sites?

Tags: php, google-tag-manager

I have a page where a php script is executed. If it succeeds a whole php-page is included via include().
This included page holds a google tag manager code.
Is this actually working for gtm or has the code to be written on the page directly instead of the page that is included?

Thanks for making this clear to me :)

Answer (score 0):

The browser will see no difference between included php code (which is parsed on the server and will be transformed to client side code when it shows in the browser) and code that's written "directly" into the page. So if your php code is correct and correctly executed then this should work just fine.